# Applescript, Chrome: Make new tab at specified index

Tags: applescript

I have this simple Applescript, which reopens active tab in new tab

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    tell first window
        set theUrl to URL of active tab
        set myTab to make new tab at end of tabs
        set URL of myTab to theUrl
    end tell
end tell
```

So I can open tab `at end of tabs` or `at beginning of tabs`, but how can I open new tab at specified index of tabs. I'd like to open it as next tab after active tab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the term `at after tab (number)`; like this

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    tell first window
        set n to active tab index
        set theUrl to URL of active tab
        set myTab to make new tab at after tab n with properties {URL:theUrl}
    end tell
end tell
```